# this.props.navigation is always Not defined

Tags: navigation, react-navigation

I am always receiving the error ( TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.navigate')). I have tried so many solutions and all did Not work. All resulting in same error. Could you please check my code and tell me what is the problem?

Here is my code.
Can you please assist me:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { FlatList,TouchableOpacity, Text, Button, View,Image, ActivityIndicator, Platform} from 'react-native';

export default class Project extends Component {
 

  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
    isLoading: true,
    }

  }

  render() {

    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}>
          <ActivityIndicator />
        </View>
      );
    }

    return (

<View style={styles.MainContainer} >

 <FlatList       
          data={ this.state.dataSource }        
          ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}
          renderItem={({item}) => 
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => this.props.navigation.navigate('DetailPage') 
           
            } style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>                
            <Text style={styles.FlatListItemStyle}  > {item.title} </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        }
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}    
 />
</View>           
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
       return fetch('http://192.152.79.6/lcu/pages/testReactNative')
         .then((response) => response.json())
         .then((responseJson) => {
           this.setState({
             isLoading: false,
             dataSource: responseJson
           }, function() {
            
           });
         })
         .catch((error) => {
           console.error(error);
         });
     }

FlatListItemSeparator = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: 1,
          width: "100%",
          backgroundColor: "#607D8B",
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you added the screen 'Detail Page' in your navigation stack?

Comment: No How to do so? I'm new to react native

Answer (score 0):

I have added those and it worked:

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
```

In the end of the App.js file:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function MyStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Project} />
      <Stack.Screen name="DetailPage" component={DetailPage} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyStack />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Happy coding!!